# BigQuery - select last non-null value in a sequence

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to bring back the last non-null value in a user's journey.

For context, I'm viewing every action of a user in their journey in my website and the last non-null value would give me the last product list name before a user added the product to cart.

In my example, the last non-null value in the 'ProductList' column would be 'Face Masks' before the 'Add to Cart' row in the 'EventAction' column

This is the results before I used first_value in a subquery:

```
**fullVisitorId|visitStartTime|visitId|visitNumber|hitNumber|ProductList|ProductSKU|EventCat|EventAction**
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 161 | Face Masks | ABC1401 | Ecommerce | Product Impression
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 161 | Face Masks | ABC1501 | Ecommerce | Product Impression
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 161 | Face Masks | ABC1601 | Ecommerce | Product Impression 
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 161 | Face Masks | ABC1701 | Ecommerce | Product Impression
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 162 | Face Masks | ABC1801 | Ecommerce | Product Click
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 163 | NULL | ABC1801 | Ecommerce | Product View
12345XX | 1608202 | 56789 | 50 | 164 | NULL | ABC1801 | Ecommerce | Add to Cart
```

However, in my code after using 'first_value' function, I'm getting null values still. Where am I going wrong? Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
    SELECT
        FIRST_VALUE(ProductList IGNORE NULLS) 
OVER (PARTITION BY EventAction ORDER BY VisitNumber ASC, hitNumber ASC) AS NewProductList
        FROM(
        SELECT
          fullVisitorId,
          visitStartTime,
          visitId,
          visitNumber,
          hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
          CASE WHEN product.productListName = '(not set)' THEN NULL ELSE product.productListName END AS ProductList,
          product.productSKU AS ProductSKU,
          hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS EventCategory,
          hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS EventAction,
        FROM
          `tablename.ga_sessions_20200914`,
          UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
          UNNEST(hits.product) product
        WHERE
          geoNetwork.country = 'United Kingdom'
          AND fullVisitorId = '1000104589833493743'
        ORDER BY
          1,
          4 ASC,
          5 ASC
        LIMIT 10000) WHERE EventAction = 'Add to Cart'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few issues with your query

1. You partition by `EventAction` - this is incorrect - you should use some column that really present the group within which you want to identify `last non-null value` - so you can use `fullVisitorId` for example
2. Your `WHERE EventAction = 'Add to Cart'` clause is applied **before** the `LAST_VALUE` is applied thus the `NULL`

So, having above in mind (apply correct partition and moving WHERE clause outside) - below should work (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT NewProductList
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    LAST_VALUE(ProductList IGNORE NULLS) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId ORDER BY VisitNumber, hitNumber) AS NewProductList
  FROM (
        SELECT
          fullVisitorId,
          visitStartTime,
          visitId,
          visitNumber,
          hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
          CASE WHEN product.productListName = '(not set)' THEN NULL ELSE product.productListName END AS ProductList,
          product.productSKU AS ProductSKU,
          hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS EventCategory,
          hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS EventAction,
        FROM
          `tablename.ga_sessions_20200914`,
          UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
          UNNEST(hits.product) product
        WHERE
          geoNetwork.country = 'United Kingdom'
          AND fullVisitorId = '1000104589833493743'
        ORDER BY
          1,
          4 ASC,
          5 ASC
        LIMIT 10000
  )
)
WHERE EventAction = 'Add to Cart'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *last* value, then you need either a descending sort or `last_value()`.  In fact, for what you want, `first_value()` is the simpler solution:

```
    FIRST_VALUE(ProductList IGNORE NULLS) OVER
        (PARTITION BY VisitNumber ORDER BY hitNumber DESC) AS NewProductList
```

I removed `eventaction` from the expression.  It seems to have nothing to do with what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback however, 'PARTITION BY VisitNumber ASC,' this bit doesn't appear to work. Also I need the last non-null value when the row is 'Add to Cart'

Comment: @MoHawk . . . That was essentially a typo.  I think you want to partition by visit number and then order by the hits.